# Error: Template parse errors: ':svg:span' is not a known element:

Tags: html, node.js, angular, svg, visual-studio-code

Could you please help me overcome this problem in my HTML in an angular  project?

```html
<svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" width="100%" height="100%" class="ct-chart-line" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="50" y="270" width="121.04761614118304" height="20">
<span class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" style="width: 121px; height: 20px;">1
</span></foreignObject></svg>
```

Error
1. If ':svg:span' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ls">[ERROR ->]

Comment: Your namespaces are incorrect/missing. You're probably serving the page as html though and therefore you don't need them anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. maybe someone needs it.

```
<svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" width="100%" height="100%" class="ct-chart-line" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

1